# Why can't I access data in parent with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Jquery:

```
 $("input[type='text']").blur(function () {
        var id = $(this).parentsUntil('.hi').attr("data-id");


       console.log(id);

    });
```

HTML:

```
<tr data-id="1" class="hi">
        <td>0</td>
        <td><input name="ctl12" type="text" value="1333"></td>
        <td><input name="ctl14" type="text" value="sdfghjkl"></td>
        <td><input name="ctl16" type="text" value="qwsdfghj"></td>
        <td><input name="ctl18" type="text" value="452145"></td>
    </tr>
```

I want to get the `data-id` value, i.e. equal to 1 but my browser console says undefined.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parentsUntil()` returns *all* parents until it reaches the specified element (`.hi`) in this case. It doesn't return that element as well. If you want to only pull the `.hi` element, use `closest()` instead.

```
var id = $(this).closest('.hi').attr("data-id");
```

---

From jQuery's documentation:

#### `parentsUntil` (https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/)

> Description: Get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, **up to but not including** the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object.

#### `closest` (https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, **get the first element that matches the selector** by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var id = $(this).parents('.hi').attr("data-id")
```

should also work in this case